# Where does the text segment actually start?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld, elf

When linking a program with GNU ld, the text segment in the resulting ELF file should start at `0x0400000` as suggested by the output of:

```
$> ld -verbose | grep -i text-segment
PROVIDE (__executable_start = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000)); . = SEGMENT_START("text-segment", 0x400000) + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
```

However, take this simple hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
                                                                                 
int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
  printf("hello world\n");                                                       
  return 0;                                                                      
}
```

and compile it with `gcc -no-pie`, then the resulting ELF file has the following LOAD segments:

```
LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x0005a8 0x0005a8 R   0x1000                                                                                                  
LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x00014d 0x00014d R E 0x1000                                                                                                  
LOAD           0x002000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000000000402000 0x0000cc 0x0000cc R   0x1000                                                                                                  
LOAD           0x002e00 0x0000000000403e00 0x0000000000403e00 0x000230 0x000238 RW  0x1000
```

Now it looks like the segment starting at `0x401000` is the text segment since it is marked as executable, but then what is the purpose of the two segments immediately before and after it?